# Setting and retrieving server timestamp on Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am signing up a user with Firebase Authentication and then saving user details in a /users collection in Firestore from a React/Redux app. I have included a **createdAt** field that saves a Firestore server timestamp to identify when the user was created. The .set call looks like this:

```
try {
let newUser = {
  displayName,
  createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  showWizard: true,
  role: "client",
  status: "signedUp",
  schoolName,
  quiz,
  email
};
await firestore.set(`users/${currentUser.uid}`, {
  ...newUser
});
 } catch (err) {
  dispatch(asyncActionError());
  toastr.error("Something went wrong", err.message);
  throw new SubmissionError({
    _error: err.message
 });
}
```

I then want to retrieve this user document to send of analytics data to Segment, including the timestamp. The call for retrieving the data and triggering the Redux Segment action looks like this:

```
try {
const newUserDoc = await firestore.get(`users/${currentUser.uid}`);
const newUserRecord = {
  id: newUserDoc.id,
  ...newUserDoc.data()
};
console.log(newUserRecord);

dispatch({
  type: USER_SIGN_UP,
  meta: {
    analytics: [
      {
        eventType: EventTypes.identify,
        eventPayload: {
          userId: newUserRecord.id,
          traits: {
            email: newUserRecord.email,
            createdAt: newUserRecord.createdAt.toDate().toISOString(),
            displayName: newUserRecord.displayName,
            quiz: newUserRecord.quiz,
            schoolName: newUserRecord.schoolName,
            role: newUserRecord.role
          }
        }
      },
      {
        eventType: EventTypes.track,
        eventPayload: {
          event: "User Signed Up",
          properties: {
            category: "Admin",
            label: newUserRecord.quiz
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
dispatch(asyncActionFinish());
return newUserRecord;
} catch (error) {
  dispatch(asyncActionError());
  toastr.error("Something went wrong", error.message);
  throw new SubmissionError({
    _error: error.message
  });
}
```

The user document shows without any error, but the **createdAt** field is shown as null. When I check in the Firebase Console a moment later, the createdAt field is populated with the correct date.

It seems that creating the server timestamp is not finished by the time I retrieve the document. How can I make sure that getting the document will include a correct timestamp?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What if you call [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) passing options that force a read from the server?  `get({source: 'server'})`

Comment: Also, are you sure the get() is happening fully after the promise returned from `set()` is resolved?

Comment: Are you sure `newUserRecord.createdAt.toDate().toISOString()` is actually returning a string? If it's returning null, it would explain why null is being retrieve!

Comment: @DougStevenson I will try the force read, thanks! Unless I am overlooking something I am awaiting the set call before continuing to the next try catch block and then retrieving it. It also returns all the other values correctly.

Comment: @JakeSteam I also console logged the bare newUserRecord object and createdAt was null too. Moment later in the Firebase Console it shows correctly as a server timestamp.

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried the get({source: 'server'}) option, but it did not resolve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I"m having trouble trying to find a way to render a date that is in the database in react.